# BeautifulSoup4 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.6

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7

I have installed bs4 using

```
apt-get install python-bs4
```

When I attempt to run a script:

```
import urllib2
import bs4
url = "http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007C9N4H8"
web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page_text = web_page.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_text)
print soup.title.string`
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bs4.py", line 4, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "/home/pbmac/tmp/bs4.py", line 8, in <module>
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_text)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'
```

YET - when I run it direetly from within python:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> import bs4
>>> url = "http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007C9N4H8"
>>> web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> page_text = web_page.read()
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_text)
>>> print soup.title.string
Amazon.com: The Muppets (2011): Jason Segel, Amy Adams, Chris Cooper, Rashida Jones: Amazon Instant Video
```

Which IS me the correct answer.

WHY does it run directly from python - but NOT as a separate file?

Thanks
pat

Answer (score 1):

You named your file `bs4.py`. So Python imports that file instead of the `bs4` module and throws an error as your file doesn't contain anything called `BeautifulSoup`.

Use another name for your file.

Comment: Okay - I am officially embarrassed....but thanks FLorian for pointing out such a GLARING mistake.